# Enter exact rational numbers easily with decimal notation

Tags: number-representation

Is there a simple way to enter decimal numbers such as 0.123 so that Mathematica interprets it as an exact rational number 123/1000?

Comment: `Rationalize[0.123]`

Comment: `Rationalize` does have limitations, though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Could you explain it a bit?

Comment: @YiWang `Rationalize[0.333333]`, `Rationalize[0.3333333333333]`, and the explanation in the docs: "Rationalize[x] yields x unchanged if there is no rational number close enough to x to satisfy the condition |p/q-x| < c/q^2, with c chosen to be 10^-4."

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! Nice to learn that.

Comment: @YiWang You're welcome! :)  Even `Rationalize[0.333333333, 0]` does not do what the OP wants.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sometimes [it doesn't work](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=8538967#8538967) even if the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: @rm-rf It's a question of precision: ``Rationalize@{5.4 10^10, 5.4 10^11, 5.4`17 10^11}``  I don't know the answer, just the question.... :P  (Oops, just saw the answer below!)

Comment: I wonder can we use $PreRead to convert entered decimals to fractions?

Answer (score 6):

No doubt this needs work to make robust:

```
 fract[s_String] := (ToExpression[StringReplace[s, "." -> ""]]/
     10^(StringLength[s] - First@First@StringPosition[s, "."]));

 $PreRead = If[Head[#] =!= Real, (
         # /. s_String :> StringReplace[s,
            a : ("." ~~ DigitCharacter ...) ~~ "*^" :> a <> " 10^"] /.
         s_String :> StringReplace[s, a : (
          (DigitCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ DigitCharacter ...) |
          (DigitCharacter ... ~~ "." ~~ DigitCharacter ..)
             ) :> "fract[\"" <> a <> "\"]"] ), #, #] &


 (1.23 + .1*^4 x) /Sin[ .5 a ]
```

> (123/100 + 1000 x) Csc[a/2]

Two  known issues:  this breaks if you use explicit precision `backtic` notation, or if your input contains floats within strings.

Comment: How about `$Pre = # /. r_Real :> RuleCondition[Round[r, 10^-Ceiling@Precision@r]] &`

Comment: The point is to work with the actual text entered to avoid some of the issues raised in the comments arising from conversion to/from machine precision.  (As a practical matter those issues may not be important, and using `$Pre` like that is clearly cleaner and more robust )

Comment: May be a good idea to append `/; StringMatchQ[s, RegularExpression["[+-]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+"]]` to your `fract`: this will avoid all the possible breakage with unexpected formats of the string, returning unevaluated expression instead.

Comment: @Ruslan: By "append to the end of `fract`" do you mean exactly this?:  `fract[s_String] := (ToExpression[StringReplace[s, "." -> ""]]/
     10^(StringLength[s] - First@First@StringPosition[s, "."]));/; StringMatchQ[s, RegularExpression["[+-]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+"]]`

Comment: @theorist not quite: insert it before the trailing semicolon — to make the pattern conditional

Comment: @Ruslan I encountered a case in which your suggested addition causes george2079's code  to break where it otherwise would have been fine:  When there is a trailing decimal point (e.g., 100./3).  One might encounter these if you've deliberately added trailing decimals to numericize evaluations within a notebook, and then use george's code to conveniently reevaluate the notebook using exact numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limitations described in the comments, a possibility is to use Ratiolize[x,0] in combination with SetPrecision or SetAccuracy. E.g.:

```
Rationalize[SetPrecision[0.33333, 5], 0]
```

> 1/3

While

```
Rationalize[SetAccuracy[0.3333, 5], 0] (* one less 3 *)
```

> 3332 / 9997

The point is to set Accuracy or Precision to the number of digits that would be normally entered to represent (conventionally) the desired rational as a floating point number.

Comment: I think the OP wants the outputs to be `33333/100000` and `3333/10000` respectively, but I think the simplest way to *enter* these numbers is `33333*^-5` and `3333*^-4`, or as fractions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 it's not really simplest if you want to be able to append digits (e.g. in a manual binary search): you have to carefully count the digits to make sure your order of magnitude isn't off and that you didn't to forget to change the exponent after you appended a new digit.

Comment: @Ruslan If counting digits is a factor in a particular case, what's simpler than the second option, [fractions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9s2Wp.png), in which counting seems unnecessary?

Comment: @MichaelE2 well, that's better, but inconvenient — it's always best to have to change _one_ thing to get what you need. The simplest way would be to define a function, which would do it all for you, as `fract` in [george2079's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46169/5208).

Comment: @Ruslan I see what you mean. What seems simpler depends on context. E.g., how many conversions/entries do you have to do and how often. My personal, and admittedly parochial, experience is limited to infrequent and few conversions. Mostly nowadays they arise from converting parameters in SE questions to exact values, although `Rationalize` is usually sufficient. It hardly seems simpler to dredge up or write a function, when I can type the fraction in more quickly than I can find and type the function command. But it's different for even a moderate amount of data.