# Why does Mathematica evaluate Sin[2.0] but not Sin[2]?

Tags: numerics, evaluation

I can't understand why is it that

```
In[88]:= Sin[2]
Out[88]= Sin[2]
```

while

```
In[89]:= Sin[2.0]
Out[89]= 0.909297
```

I even tried

```
In[90]:= 2 + Sin[2]
Out[90]= 2 + Sin[2]
```

thinking that it might force the evaluation, but apparently not...

Now, I know that I can just do this

```
In[91]:= N[Sin[2]]
Out[91]= 0.909297
```

but I am curious why doesn't just `Sin[2]` work.

Even though the *Documentation Center* page for `Sin[x]` contains *Possible Issues* examples this behavior is not mentioned.

I know from some experience with **Python** and **C** that expressing a integer number, e.g. **2**, as a rational number, i.e. **2.0**, can influence the way an expression is evaluated, e.g.

```
#Python code    
>>> 5 / 2
2
>>> 5 / 2.0
2.5
```

Even though I personally don't agree with this behavior (I think there should be different operators for *integer division* and *rational division* since it will always cause some confusion) if you just see some examples it becomes clear what happens.

Here I don't have any idea what **Mathematica** thinks when it sees `Sin[2]`

***Note***:

- I'm using **Mathematica v7.0**
- I'm basically a beginner.
- I don't plan and have time to go through a tutorial, I just wanted to play around. I expected the simple/common things to behave intuitively enough.
- I also appreciate if you point me to some resources where this behavior is explained.

Comment: Sin[2] is an exact expression, as simple as possible. 0.909297 is a numerical approximation. Both representations are useful in different contexts.

Comment: The difference between exact and approximate numbers in Mathematica is explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html).  `Sin[2]` simply cannot be represented in decimal notation.  It can only be *approximated* with a finite number of digits.  If you give exact input to Mathematica (integers are considered exact) then it will give you an exact output, the simplest form of which here is `Sin[2]`.  `Sin[Pi]` would give an exact `0`, `Sin[Pi/3]` would give `Sqrt[3]/2`, but you can't reduce `Sin[2]` further without using approximations.

Comment: It's good to note that you'll find the same behaviour with virtually all computer algebra systems.

Comment: Also explained [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18485/7167) but not sure if this constitutes a duplicate.

Comment: I think you got your answer already. But just to anticipate future questions: note that, in *Mathematica*, numbers expressed as decimals are not considered to be rationals, but rather reals with some associated uncertainty. This is very unusual and can lead to confusion for those used to other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mathematica tutorial on  [Numerical Precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html)

gives a brief intro of how Mathematica handles certain 
numerical inputs.  Under Documentation, Details for [Sin](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sin.html)
guides that "certain special arguments" are automatically evaluated to exact values.  But in your examples, Mathematica sees the input value of `2.` as a machine precision number and, per the Documentation "Machine-Precision Numbers", you will get a machine precision output. Otherwise, per the other answers & comments, Mathematica maintains your exact input in an exact form unless you apply numerical evaluation (e.g `N@Sin[2]`).
Try these:

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2}] 
Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2, 0.1}]
```

Note the machine precision value for step-size (0.1).   Mathematica returns machine-precision results even with the first value, x=0 (!)

```
Table[Sin[x],{x,0,2,1}]
```

...uses exact values all the way down.

Also compare:

```
Sin[2]*Pi
N@Sin[2]*Pi
Sin[2]*Pi // N
N[Sin[2]*Pi]
```

The last 3 give the same numerical value, using alternate syntax. The function `N` can also be used with a second value  to provide n-digits of precision  e.g `N[Sin[2]*Pi,10]` gives 10 digit precision.  See Documents for [N](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html?q=N&lang=en).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Given that Sin[2] is evaluated to the exact value but for a number like 1.23 Sin[1.23] evaluates to a machine precision number the following question may arise: How do I evaluate Sin[1.23] to exact value?
It occurred to me that in this case I could use Sin[123/100].
This could be extended to other decimal numbers.

Comment: @DonComo yes, that's right. You can either use `Rationalize`  to whatever tolerance you think appropriate, or `SetPrecision[..., Infinity]` if you want to treat the floating point number like the rational that it really is.

Comment: Funnily enough, @DonComo, this `N[Sin[2], 2]^2 + N[Cos[2], 2]^2 == 1` is `True`, although you may get a very different result in traditional programming languages. Here is what you get in **Ruby** (irb): ` Math.sin(2).round(2)**2 + Math.cos(2).round(2)**2 == 1` => false. The reason is that _Mathematica_ keeps track of precision and, at the level of precision requested, the two expressions are the same :)

Comment: @caya My hunch is that, even though you use N[] on separate terms, *Mathematica* evaluates the expression without N[] and than uses N[] on the resulting expression. But this is just speculation, I currently have only a limited understanding of the language.

Comment: @DonComo based on [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42141/enter-exact-rational-numbers-easily-with-decimal-notation) you can make your own function      `Clear[newsine];newsine[x_]:=Sin[Rationalize[x]]` and call it using `newsine[1.23]` etc

Comment: @DonComo The two `N` are evaluated *separately*, as you can verify with `Trace`.  The reason why it gives true is what caya said.  Mathematica keeps track of precision and up to 2 digits the equality holds.

Comment: @Szabolcs Did you find a precision for which the equality does not hold?
I've tried this `Manipulate[
 N[Sin[2], prec]^2 + N[Cos[2], prec]^2 == 1, {prec, 2, 10, 1}]` and it shows `True` every time...

Comment: @DonComo We're getting pretty deep into how precision works in Mathematica, and I don't think the comments are a good place to discuss this.  There are other reasons too why it gives `True`, e.g. the fact that `==` has a tolerance for MachinePrecision numbers.  But generally: if you use MachinePrecision, the calculations are fast, but they're done at a fixed precision and there's no precision tracking.  So often you'll get a very small number where you'd expect zero (e.g. substituting the solution into an equation and evaluating numerically). You can join the chat for details.

Comment: @Szabolcs Edit: I understand now what happens, I've just tested with `Trace` and you are right. Sorry, it's late on my side :) 
Thanx

Comment: @DonComo `Equal` has a tolerance of 7 bits for machine precision or higher; `SameQ` has a tolerance of 1 bit. caya's example basically asks if `1.\`1.7 == 1.\`16.` or not. The answer is clearly yes, regardless of the tolerance. But this tolerance is another thing to watch out for as it is not just unexpected for most people but also poorly documented.