# Can I change the default behavior so that "0.1" is interpreted as "1/10" automatically?

Tags: machine-precision, arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

Consider the function

`f[a_] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[a + Log[x]], {x, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]`.

With this definition, I cannot call `f[0.1]` (for example) without Mathematica throwing an error, since "0.1" is interpreted automatically as a machine number with `MachinePrecision` (about 16), whereas the integration requires 30 digits of precision.

But when I enter `0.1`, of course I really mean `1/10`. One solution is to enter `f[1/10]`, but this is very inconvenient to do every time, especially because my real functions involve many parameters with long strings of decimal numbers. What's the best way around this issue? Ideally, I'd like Mathematica to interpret `0.1` as `1/10` automatically, as mentioned in the title.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I would like any decimal number input be treated as the exact mathematical number with the same name. For example, `0.###` should become `###/1000`. As pointed out in the comments, `Rationalize` converts `0.33333333` to `1/3`, which I would consider a problem for my case. I would like Mathematica to treat decimal number input as exact numbers without rounding to any finite precision, nor assuming that I intended a "close" but different rational number.

---

Another option would be to change the function definition:

`f[a_] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[Rationalize[a] + Log[x]], {x, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]`

or

`f[a_] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[SetPrecision[a, \[Infinity]] + Log[x]], {x, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]`

But this too would be quite inconvenient to do for every function I use. I also worry about the fact that `SetPrecision[0.1, \[Infinity]]` does *not* give `1/10`. So all this makes me wonder what the "right" method is.

Comment: You could use `$PreRead` to replace `"0.1"` with `RowBox[{"1", "/", "10"}]`, I guess. For my money, I would personally go with entering `1/10`.  Your comment about it suggests you might not just be worried about `0.1` but other decimal numbers.  It's unclear to me which ones I should worry about, though.  Perhaps instead of `$PreRead$`, you could use `$Pre` to replace real numbers by their rationalizations.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I was using `0.1` as an example, but in reality there are many arbitrary decimal values I may want to enter.

Comment: Do you want all decimal input to be converted to decimal fractions?

Comment: Yes, so for example, `0.###` would be converted to `###/1000`.

Comment: Even `0.3333333333333` should not become `1/3` as happens when you feed it to `Rationalize`?  (Maybe this should be clarified in the question, and not just left in the comments.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42141/enter-exact-rational-numbers-easily-with-decimal-notation

Comment: Another suggestion is to form your list of inputs in the decimal fraction format you need, then apply the function to that list, if the use case causes a large overhead with the methods suggested here, as is noted by those that have provided them.

Comment: You should be aware that for a computer, [`0.1` is never `1/10`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125694/22013).

Comment: @corey979 I think IBM still makes computers (mainframes) that have a native decimal floating-point mode (as well as a binary one).  I guess *Mathematica* doesn't run on them, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Since `f` makes use of a numeric technique, the argument `a` should be restricted to being numeric. Set the precision of `a` to at least the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) used in [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html).

```
f[a_?NumericQ, wp : _Integer : 30] := Module[{ap = SetPrecision[a, 
  Max[wp, Precision[a]]]},
  NIntegrate[Sqrt[ap + Log[x]], {x, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> wp]]

f[1/10]

(* 11.3397714471112499234083518037 *)

f[0.1]

(* 11.3397714471112499447483664367 *)

f[0.1, 20]

(* 11.339771447111249944 *)
```

Comment: This has the unfortunate problem that `SetPrecision[0.1,30]` does not give `0.1` (with 29 zeros), but rather `0.100000000000000005551115123126`. Whereas I need `0.1` to be `0.1`

Comment: Then use `Rationalize[#, 0] &`

Comment: The issue with `Rationalize`, I'm finding, is that it refuses to work on decimals that are too "messy." For example `Rationalize[0.362861]` just returns the input, valid only to `MachinePrecision`. Try `Rationalize[0.362861]~SetPrecision~50` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: That is what the `0` is for in my earlier comment, i.e., `Rationalize[0.362861, 0]` or `0.362861//Rationalize[#, 0] &`

Comment: Ah, now I see. So this method will definitely work. I'm still curious to know whether this could be done automatically for all numerical inputs, using `$Pre`, as Michael E2 suggested in a comments.

Comment: It could be done; **however**, the performance penalty would be very significant if done for all real numbers. It is best done when needed/appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you're after:

```
rd = With[{t = RealDigits[#][[1]]},,FromDigits[t]/10^Length@t] &;
```

E.g.:

> rd[0.12345675785894491727276262524416723451]

> 12345675785894491727276262524416723451/100000000000000000000000000000000000000

Compare:

```
Rationalize[0.12345675785894491727276262524416723451, 0]
```

> 2986272931814910240/24188817069267814669

Specifying precision as part of the input can address this:

```
Rationalize[0.12345675785894491727276262524416723451`100, 0]
```

> 12345675785894491727276262524416723451/100000000000000000000000000000000000000

I suppose a simple wrapper could be used to automate the conversion when calling your functions.

Comment: Oh. I didn't see this before I added my lame alternative (now rolled back)... +1 -- This is shorter: `rd = FromDigits@*RealDigits` -- @WillG, this will work with `$Pre`.  E.g. `$Pre = rd;`

Comment: @MichaelE2 - ah, well done - I'd forgotten that the output of realdgits can directly be used with fromdigits.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `$PreRead` approach:

```
$PreRead = # /. 
    s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] :> 
     With[{pos = StringPosition[s, "."]},
      RowBox[{StringDrop[s, First[pos]], "/", 
         10^(StringLength[s] - pos[[1, 1]])}]
       /; Length[pos] === 1] &;

(* new Input cell *)
0.231 + 27 Exp[10.856 x]
```

> ```
> (*  231/1000 + 27 E^(1357 x/125)  *)
> ```

```
(* new Input cell *)
$PreRead =.    (* reset *)

%% // N
```

> ```
> (*  0.231 + 27. 2.71828^(10.856 x)  *)
> ```

Gratuitous remark: I never use `$PreRead` (anymore).  I think the way it can mess with the input is a potential headache and, in this case, I'd rather put up with the inconvenience of typing `10856/1000`.

Comment: Note that this works because you parse the string. One cannot recover exact decimal input after conversion to approximate binary, so `Rationalize`-based approaches cannot do exactly what the OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Exact conversion to the underlying IEEE-754 machine-precision number can be done with `SetPrecision[x,∞]`:

```
x = 1/3 // N
(*    0.333333    *)

SetPrecision[x, ∞]
(*    6004799503160661/18014398509481984    *)
```

So you see that $1/3$ is represented internally as $6\,004\,799\,503\,160\,661\times2^{-54}$.

Comment: The OP want the denominator to be a power of ten, not a power of two.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I couldn't quite figure out what the OP wants. Rounding to the nearest decimal is a tricky operation and has been discussed a lot in the past.